# How to special the mysql sock path in clsql?

Tags: mysql, common-lisp, clsql

When I connected to mysql using clsql,the following error occurred

> While trying to connect to database localhost:3306/root/
>     using database-type MYSQL:
>     Error 2002 / Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
>     has occurred.
>     [Condition of type SQL-CONNECTION-ERROR]

My mysql.sock path is "/home/myhome/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock",how
  can I change the default sock path in clsql?
  Here is my code, (SBCL 1.0.50 ,mysql 5.0,clsql-20130128-git)

> (asdf:operate 'asdf:load-op 'clsql)
>
> (in-package #:clsql-user)
>
> (clsql:connect '("localhost" "username" "password" "dbname" 3306 ) :database-type :mysql)"

Comment: I have a /etc/my.cnf configuation,and I have read mysql-api.lisp and mysql-sql.lisp,it seems I should use (database-name-from-spec (host db user password &optional port
  options)).
  In mysql-api.lisp (uffi:def-enum mysql-option
  (:connect-timeout
  ....
  :reconnect
  :ssl-verify-server-cert)).

  mysql manual:
  >socket=path ;;maybe what I need.

  I think I should write "options" like this 
  > (:socket "/home/myhome/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock")
  or ("socket" "/home/myhome/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock")

  But they were wrong,I'm a newbie in cl,how can I do to get them work togther?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a `~/.my.cnf` or (if you have root access) `/etc/my.cnf` file and including a client setting for the socket, `libmysqlclient` might pick this up.

Failing that (or if you don't want to make a global change) the doc suggests you can specify a list of MySQL options as a separate assoc list  http://clsql.b9.com/manual/connect.html which get passed into [mysql_options()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-options.html)

Answer (score 0):

Funny,the answer is that change the host from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"